# Edit all the parts of a cell fractured object at the same time

Tags: objects, edit-mode

I'm a beginner in Blender and I was trying to do [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTq9sLQOiVs&list=PLzmyR17f55-LVbgnzhS4Xl9zJ3dSCdYW3&index=1) This is a planet being fractured, so cell fracture addon is used.

At 6:20, after cell fracture has been applied and I have switched to layer 2, it is said to press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+RightMouseButton on one of the pieces so that it becomes possible to work on all the pieces at the same time in edit mode (by joining them).

The problem is that it does not work for me. I'm using Blender version 2.71.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "not work"? What happens instead?

Comment: Actually, nothing. Here is what I get on layer 2: http://i58.tinypic.com/2ivudd.jpg It is the same as is shown in the video. I then try to press Shift+RightMouseButton on a piece, but I am just not able to: nothing happens. The result of this is that I cannot even switch to edit mode or join anything at all...

Comment: Does anything happen if you just click with RMB (without shift)?

Comment: Yes. It is selecting only one piece: the piece I have clicked on, so the only option I see to select all the pieces would be to click on them one by one...

Comment: Try selecting the one piece so that you have an active object, then border select the rest with B.

Answer (score 1):

When joining objects, one object must be chosen to join all the other selected objects too.
In this case it doesn't really make a difference which object that is, but if you had different modifiers or materials on the objects, blender needs to know which object's modifiers should be used on the resulting combined object.

Normally this is done with the *[Active object](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects/Selecting#Selections_and_the_Active_Object)*, which is outlined in yellow and in most cases is the last selected object. Note that an object can be active without being selected.

Right after running the cellfracture operator is a rare case where there is no active object. You need to define one by selecting an object, but after you have done that, that object is active until you select another object and it becomes the new active object.

In the tutorial he uses <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd> on a already selected object (orange outline) to make it active (yellow outline) without affecting the rest of the objects. I'm not sure why this didn't work for you (are you sure the object's outline didn't change color?), but you can just as easily select all the objects after one is active, e.g. with box select (<kbd>B</kbd>) or if you really want to select *all* the visible objects, <kbd>A</kbd>.
Once you have your active object and selection, you can join them with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> or the join button in the toolshelf.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default blender uses the right mouse button to select items. Shift right mouse button will then add another item to the selection, or if an already selected item is clicked then the item will become the "active" item, that is the one highlighted slightly lighter that the others.

If you change your preferences to select with the left mouse button then you will need to use shift left mouse button instead.